# Exposing a ECS Service to the net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-networking

I have created a ECS cluster and created a number of services. But I want one of the services  be accessed to the outside world. That service will then interact with the other services.

Created an ECS cluster
Created services.
Created the apps loaded into a docker container.
I updated the security group to allow outside access

But under network interfaces on my console I cant find any reference to my security group I created. The security groups created are there.

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_service" {
  name            = "my_service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.fetcher_service.id
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.my_service.family}:${max(aws_ecs_task_definition.my_service.revision, data.aws_ecs_task_definition.my_service.revision)}"
  desired_count   = 0
  network_configuration {
    subnets         = var.vpc_subnet_ids
    security_groups = var.zuul_my_group_ids
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
}
```

Am I missing any steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you tp LRuttens answer. I set  desired count to 1. and under network instances I see a network associated with my securitygroup for that ECS service,

Answer (score 3):

If desired count is set to 0, probably no containers will be spun up in the first place and no network interfaces will be allocated. Maybe that's the issue.

Set the desires count to something larger than zero to test this.